# How to handle multiple pages of an Iframe in Python selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, iframe

I am scraping some date with Selenium. Everything seems to work fine. But the problem is that while trying to collect the data across multiple pages of an iFrame with a loop I am facing a problem that `driver.page_source` returns the data only for the first page. So, loops switches between iframe pages but the source remains same.

```
    ...
    iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0] #find data iframe
    driver.switch_to_frame(iframe) #switch to iframe
    pageo = 1
    while len(data)<numo:
        if pageo != 1:
            #continue
            link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,  '''//a[@onclick='set_current_page("'''+str(pageo) + '''");']''')))
            link.click()
            time.sleep(2)
            #driver.find_element_by_xpath(('''//a[@onclick='set_current_page("'''+str(pageo) + '''");']''')).click()
        #time.sleep(0.5)
        html_source = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "html.parser")
        table = soup.findAll('table')[1]
        table_body = table.find('tbody')
        rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            cols = row.find_all('td')
            cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
            data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])
            dynamic_data_entry()
        pageo = pageo + 1
    ...
```

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Just a guess, but I notice that the code is only waiting 2 seconds for the page to load after clicking the link.  Is there something consistent on the page that you can wait for to know that the page has advanced?  Maybe a page number is displayed?

Comment: if you watch the code run, do you actually see the click on the link cause the page in the frame to advance?  maybe it hasn't changed.

Comment: Yes. The link.click() causes the frame to advance and shows different data. However, page_source remains same.

Comment: perhaps the entire page is refreshing, so you need to switch_to_frame() again within the loop?

Comment: I am not sure but I believe the problem is with the website. I just checked again. And it seems that the data does not change with the click while the iframe advances to the next page.

Comment: Perhaps driver.page_source is not getting the content of that iframe?  Instead of using BeautifulSoup here, you could just continue to use WebDriver to pull the rows from your table (something like find_elements_by_css_selector('table:nth-of-type(1) tbody tr')) etc.

Comment: I contacted website admin and he confirmed the problem is with the website! Thanks for your comments!